# Taxonomy Hierarchy in Dropdown Select

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, dropdown, hierarchy

I have managed a dropdown menu for custom taxonomies that allow to jump from one term page to other, but in the dropdown list taxonomies are not hierarchized. Can anybody help to correct the code?

I tried to change some parameters in the Javascript but I'm not really in it. I can work a little with php.

```
        <form style="width: 100%;">
                <?php

                $categories = get_categories('taxonomy=city');
                $select = "<select style='margin-top: 15px; width: 100%; height: 30px; font-family : Glegoo; font-size: 12pt' name='cat' id='cat' class='postform'>n";
                $select .= "<option style='height: 10px; font-weight: bold' value='-1'> SELECT ANOTHER CITY </option>n";

                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    if ($category->count > 0) {
                        $select .= "<option value='" . $category->slug . "'>" . $category->name . "</option>";
                    }
                }

                $select .= "</select>";

                echo $select;
                ?>

                <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");

                    function onCatChange() {
                        if (dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value != -1) {
                            location.href = "<?php echo home_url();?>/city/" + dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value + "/";
                        }
                    }

                    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
                    --></script>

    </form>
```

Comment: If the answer i provided below was helpful please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Hallo MrK, thank you for your answe, I tried your code but it works the same as before. Primary Categories don't show off and the menu is not hierarchized ... https://www.indoorskydiving.world/city/canada/edmonton/